# export data in CSV formate

Tags: javascript

I Wrote a javascript function to export data into csv formate . Currently getting data in csv file but not in proper ways. I mean they are not in there respective columns. I have a table on page and want data inside that table to be exported to csv file.

```
function createCSV() {
    alert('entered'); 
    var csv = '';
    $('table[id$="table"]').find('tr:has(th)').each(function() {
    var listThValues = [];
    $(this).find('th').each(function() {
    listThValues.push($(this).find('div').html());
   });
   csv += listThValues.join()  + '\r\n';
});

   $('table[id$="table"]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
   var listThValues = [];
   $(this).find('td').each(function() {
    listThValues.push($(this).html());
   });
   csv += listThValues.join()  + '\r\n';
});
//var filename = 'file.csv';
//var blobby = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/plain'});
var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);


$("#export").attr({
    'download': 'test.csv'
        ,'href': csvData
        ,'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any operation involving adding a comma to the csv variable. Are you sure you know the format you want to output?

Comment: Besides that, I believe what you are missing is a ',' character in your `join()` calls.